# Word for persons with similar faces

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name of people with faces that look alike.For instance those with similar names are known as namesake

Comment: Doppelganger, or look-alike

Comment: @mahmudkoya you should add a definition and put that in an answer (I’d upvote it!).

Comment: I agree that doppelganger is the best single-word answer. I was going to add it as an answer myself, but I wanted to give @mahmudkoya the opportunity first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spitting image:   Jack is the spitting image of John.

Double:           Jack is an exact double of John.

Ringer:           Jack is a dead ringer for John.

Comment: add citations - good answer

Answer (score 5):

> **[doppelganger](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/doppelganger)**: someone who looks like someone else.
>
> **[Lookalike](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lookalike)**:
>
> someone who is very similar in appearance to another person,
>   especially a famous person.